How to hide the checkboxes of the parent node in the dxTreeList?
I need to hide the parent node's checkbox (Boolean cell) in the tree List.
I use DevExpress with jQuery. I am new to this tech. Kindly anyone help me out to solve this problem with efficient way.
I have searched for the solutions through the internet. If I implement them, I have to restructure my saving mechanism of the dxTreeList. I used the built-in checkbox (Boolean cell), but the resources say to use the cell template with custom checkbox.
My code implementation:
dataSource: dataForControls,
id: "id",
parentId: "parentId",
editing: {
   mode: "batch",
   allowAdding: false,
   allowUpdating: true,
   allowDeleting: false,
},
columns: [
   { dataField: "pageName", caption: "Page / Control", allowEditing: false },
   { dataField: "pageAccess", caption: "Has Access", allowEditing: true, dataType: "boolean",
}
]

I need to hide the checkbox of the parent node.
